# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/EnumConverter

Tags: css, javafx, charts, scenebuilder

0

I'm creating a JavaFX app in scenebuilder.

i have import [GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx] project where i'm using Gradle, JDK 11

I'm using their 'ChartFxSample.java'

When i run the sample, build is FAILED

> Task :App.main() FAILED
>   SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
>   Exception in Application start method
>   Exception in Application stop method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

```
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/EnumConverter
>   Caused by: 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/EnumConverter

```
at de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.AbstractAxisParameter.<init>(AbstractAxisParameter.java:188)
at de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.AbstractAxis.<init>(AbstractAxis.java:112)
at de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.AbstractAxis.<init>(AbstractAxis.java:160)
at de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.DefaultNumericAxis.<init>(DefaultNumericAxis.java:137)
at de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.DefaultNumericAxis.<init>(DefaultNumericAxis.java:102)
at App.start(App.java:60)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
... 1 more
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EnumConverter
>   Caused by: 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.EnumConverter

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 15 more
```

Exception running application App

Execution failed for task ':App.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/jbr/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Looks like your error is purely down to not having a logging provider (SLF4J) in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution where the dependencies was:

```
implementation 'de.gsi.chart:chartfx-chart:8.0.0'
```

and it should be:

```
implementation 'de.gsi.chart:chartfx-chart:11.0.0'
```